# PHPExcel - AutoSize

Tags: phpexcel, php

Генерирую страницу с помощью PHPExcel, ставлю на колонки авто-размер, но AutoSize нормально ставится только на некоторые столбы. **С какими свойствами AutoSize может конфликтовать&** Вот код проставки авторазмера:

```
for ($i=2; $i<$maxColumn; $i++)
{
    $sheet->getColumnDimensionByColumn($i)->setAutoSize(true);
}
```

Comment: если есть объединение ячеек, то авторазмер не будет работать.

Comment: > то авторазмер не будет работать.

вот блин, там где не работает на самом деле есть объединения. Есть пути решения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Припоминаю такую функцию:

```
$sheet->calculateColumnWidths();
```

Попробуйте с ней поиграться.

Инфо: [$sheet->calculateColumnWidths()](http://www.contao-docs.org/docs/PHPExcel/html/class_p_h_p_excel___worksheet.html#a25037b0b5d43dca42c5613218a6ef346)

Comment: эх, пересчет ширины тоже не помогает, и явно это связано с тем самым объединением ячеек... Попробую пошаманить с ручным определением занимаемой ширины :)

Answer (score 2):

В общем сделал что-то типо этого:

```
$font = new PHPExcel_Style_Font();
$font->setSize(11);
for ($i=2; $i<$maxColumn; $i++)
{
    $widthColumn = PHPExcel_Shared_Font::getTextWidthPixelsApprox(
            $headerTexts[$i-2],
            $font);
    $widthColumn = ($widthColumn) / 7 + 1.5;
    if ($widthColumn > 25) $widthColumn = 25;
    $sheet->getColumnDimensionByColumn($i)->setWidth($widthColumn);
}
```

формула `$widthColumn = ($widthColumn) / 7 + 1.5;` подобрал сам, более менее подходит :)